# Передача данных в компоненты vue с помощью шины событий

Tags: javascript, vue.js, события

Начал изучать `vue` столкнулся с проблемой,есть сестринские компоненты, их 4 штуки, при выборе в селекте "Добавить новую организацию" (компонент `CompanyRegistration`) вся информация введеная пользователем отправляется с помощью `EventBus` в методе `add_company_to_hash`. Затем, название организации и форма добавляются в селект (компонент `PersonalAccount`, в массив `companies: []`),при выборе организации ,вся информация должна передаваться в компонент `AllCompanies`. Но вот тут и возникла проблема, что информация появляется в компоненте (передаю я так же с помощью `EventBus`) , только когда выбираю второй! раз в селекте строчку с компанией, почему так не могу понять. Прикрепляю код
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPjjKx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В твоей ситeации не нужно использовать EventВus. Достаточно нативной реактивность VueJs.

Если у тебя есть объект с массивом организаций то тебе надо просто передать его во все места где он используется, и при обновлении он будет обновлённым во всех компонентах. Все шаблоны зависящие от этого массива будут автоматически перерисованы.

В твоей ситуации лучше всего использовать [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/) для хранения общего состояния приложения. То есть организации надо поместить внутрь контейнера Vuex.

Если без vuex просто помести его в рутовый компонент, к нему есть доступ у любого дочернего компонента через `el.$root`.

При добавлении новой организации через `organizations.push(...)` всё шаблоны зависящие от этого массива будут перерисованы.

Реактивность VueJS - [документация](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad).
Использование реативности с массивами - [документация](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85).

Comment: Во Vuex пока не хочу влезать, хочется, все таки, просто с vue разобраться. А вот доступ через $root не знал. Спасибо,буду пробовать

Answer (score 2):

C мнением @Дмитрий Полянинб я согласен, однако это не ответ на вопрос. 
Твой код работает не так, как задумано по нескольким причинам:

1) Пересчет индекса компании (`whichIndex`) повешен на клик, а нужно на `change`. Если бы ты повесил обработчик как положено, то у тебя даже так не работало, как работает сейчас. Повезло)

2)  Событие `company_index` эмитится еще до того, как будет создан компонент `AllCompanies`.

Таким образом, в связи с вышесказанным, получается, что компонент  `AllCompanies` не слышит события `company_index`, т.к. оно уже прошло. Потом, когда идет клик, индекс пересчитывается, генериться событие `company_index` - и все работает как ты и задумывал.

Чтобы реализовать функционал, так как ты задумал - данные для `AllCompanies` необходимо передавать в `props`, через `router`

Comment: Спасибо....я совсем забыл, что пропс можно передавать через роуты. Попробую оба варианта

Comment: Вариантом, который предложил @Дмитрий Полянин, все работает, но я хочу разобраться и с передачей props через роуты. Прочитал документацию, что-то не могу понять, если честно