# Передать данные между дочерними компонентами при клике Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Есть два дочерних компонента (item.vue и item2.vue), связанные друг с другом (они вложены в 1 общий leftbl.vue).

Контент в item.vue и item2.vue это  ul -> li, при клике на отдельный li, нужно передать его данные (текст и src картинки) в другой дочерний компонент (rightbl.vue).

Как это можно реализовать, пробовал через $emit, но получалось передавать только из одного компонента (item.vue или item2.vue), когда подключаю $emit к двум компонентам, то ничего не работает.

item.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <li @click="viewDetailsClicked"  class="cryptoblock">
        <img  :src=getImgUrl(item.src) alt="">
        <p>{{item.text}}</p>

    </li>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['item'],
    data(){
            return{

            }},
    methods: {
        getImgUrl(pic) {
            return require('../assets/' + pic);
        },
        viewDetailsClicked(){
                this.$emit("viewData",this.item.clas);
            }
    }
}
</script>
```

item2.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <li @click="viewDetailsClicked"  class="cryptoblock">
        <img  :src=getImgUrl(item1.src) alt="">
        <p>{{item1.text}}</p>

    </li>
</div>
</template>
```

leftbl.vue

```
<template>

<div class="hello">
    <div class="leftb">

        <div class="firstb">
            <h2>1. Отдаете</h2>
           <Item v-for='item of items' :key="item.clas" :item="item"  @viewData="viewData"></Item>   
        </div>

        <div   class="secondb">
            <h2>2. Получаете</h2>
            <Item2 v-for='item1 of items1' :key="item1.class" :item1="item1" @viewData1="viewData1"></Item2>  


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Item from './item.vue';
import Item2 from './item2.vue';
import _ from "lodash";

export default {
     components: {
            Item,
            Item2
        },
    name: 'Leftbl',


    data() {
        return {


            items: [{
                    clas: '1',
                    src: "BTC.png",
                    text: 'Bitcoin',
                    backgroundcolor: "#f4b41f"
                },
                {
                    clas: '2',
                    src: "USDT.png",
                    text: 'Tether',
                    backgroundcolor: "#16a085",
                    color: "#ffffff"
  }
                ,
                {
                    clas: '3',
                    src: "GAS.png",
                    text: 'Neo',
                    backgroundcolor: "#34c150"
                },
                {
                    clas: '4',
                    src: "ETH.png",
                    text: 'Ethereum',
                    backgroundcolor: "#2553a3"
                },
                {
                    clas: '5',
                    src: "EOS.png",
                    text: 'EOS',
                    backgroundcolor: "#010916",
                    color: "#ffffff"
                }

            ],

            items1: [{
                    class: '1',
                    src: "Advcash.png",
                    text: 'Advcash'
                },
                {
                    class: '2',
                    src: "Alfabank.png",
                    text: 'Alfabank'
                },
                {
                    class: '3',
                    src: "Payeer.png",
                    text: 'Payeer'
                },
                {
                    class: '4',
                    src: "Paypal.png",
                    text: 'Paypal'
                },
                {
                    class: '5',
                    src: "Payza.png",
                    text: 'Payza'
                },
                {
                    class: '6',
                    src: "Perfect-Money.png",
                    text: 'Perfect-Money'
                },
                {
                    class: '7',
                    src: "Qiwi.png",
                    text: 'Qiwi RUB'
                },
                {
                    class: '8',
                    src: "Sberbank.png",
                    text: 'Sberbank RUB'
                },
                {
                    class: '9',
                    src: "Skrill.png",
                    text: 'Skrill '
                },
                {
                    class: '10',
                    src: "Tinkoff.png",
                    text: 'Tinkoff RUB'
                }

            ]
        }
    },

    methods: {





    viewData(clas){
        let ptpt = _.find(this.items, {clas:clas});
        this.$emit("viewData", ptpt );
    },


    }











}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <div class="center">
        <Leftbl  @viewData="viewData"  />
        <Rightbl :product="selectedProduct" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
 <script>
methods:{
    viewData(product){
      this.selectedProduct = product;
    },
</script>
```

rightbl.vue

```
<template>
<div class="hello">

    <div class="rightb">
        <div class="cryptochange">
            <h2>Откуда</h2>
            <div  :style="{ backgroundColor: product.backgroundcolor, color: product.color }" class="wallet">
                <div class="top">
                    <img src="../assets/sim-card-chip.png" alt="">
                    <img  :src=getImgUrl(product.src) alt="">


</div>
                    <div class="center">

                        <p>wallet adress</p>
                        <input type="text">

</div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            сумма: <input type="text"> BTC

</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bankchange">
                        <h2>Куда</h2>

                        <div class="wallet">
                            <div class="top">
                                <img src="../assets/sim-card-chip.png" alt="">

</div>
                                <div class="center">
                                    <p>card number</p>
                                    <input type="text">

</div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        сумма: <input type="text"> RUB

</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Rightbl',

    data() {
        return {}

    },

    props: {
        product: Object,

    },
    methods: {
        getImgUrl(pic) {
            return require('../assets/' + pic);
        },
    }

}
</script>
```

для наглядности картинка, как это все должно передаваться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сейчас все передается только с компонента item.vue , если такой же функционал сделать на item2.vue то работать не будет ничего.

Comment: Приведите ваш код.

Comment: Используйте vuex. В таких случаях уже надо.

Comment: @AK добавил код

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача данных в компоненты vue с помощью шины событий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/930078/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-vue-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: @РустамГимранов ничем, одно и то же, ошибся в вопросе

Comment: @РустамГимранов  да, выводят список

Comment: @РустамГимранов исправил вопрос, может сейчас станет понятнее

Comment: Вы же ни строчки кода не поменяли из списка рекомендаций, которые в моем ответе.